# Can you prevent the usage of #pragma warning disable?

Tags: c#, pragma, software-quality, editorconfig

Recently, our team has tried to become more strict about enforcing certain code style and quality guidelines.  I'm trying to automate this as much as possible, using .editorconfig files to enforce certain rules--in many cases preventing a build instead of generating a warning that will just be ignored.

Of course, not everyone is super enthusiastic about this, and now people are just adding `#pragma disable` directives to get around the rules we are trying to enforce.  Is there any way to prevent people from doing this?  I can't seem to find any info on preventing the usage of `#pragma disable`.  I know the best way to solve this would be to foster a culture where people wouldn't even think of doing this, but I am a bit jaded about that ever happening with my team.

Comment: Sounds like a culture question, as you say. You should probably have some level of code reviews, and code has to meet a coding standard (which everyone agrees on) before it can be merged.

Comment: How would you plan to allow the pragma that are required for the build release as some feature are partially implemented and not ready ? Do you never have this case ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a _programmer_ problem, not a _programming_ problem.

Comment: @gunr2171 Yes, it may be, but then this may be the answer. Even though this should be solved on the social level, asking for a technical solution is not _wrong_. Its a similar question whether you should be enforcing code reviews or make them optional.

Comment: There is a serious training and/or culture issue here. Adding rules to some software to stop people adding pragma definitions is only going to cause more aggravation. Fix the problem at the source, ensure the developers know *why* things are being changed and need to be fixed.

Comment: Similar to the user vs program issue, if there were a way to prevent people using `#pragma disable`, what would you do when a facility was introduced to allow that function to be disabled, because certain people really *need* to perform disables? It's an arms race, nobody wins, but users lose whilst you spend effort on this rather than features they value.

Comment: @Franck No, we never use `pragma` for this.  There are other ways of doing feature toggles, though we manage that through our branching strategy.

Comment: @gunr2171 Agreed, but if catching this actually is feasible I would like to know.  It would be nice to have a culture where everyone obeyed the speed limit, but we still have speed cameras and police to enforce this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been there, done that. In the beginning, a lot of programmers will be arguing over the new rules or try to work around them, even if they where agreed on in the team. But this will eventually calm down when people get used to the rules. You should make sure that at least new code follows the rules (i.e. by consistent reviews). Old code can be adapted over time or when it needs touching. Also consider reviewing the rules after some time, maybe there are some which are not useful in your scenario and can be disabled again. When enabling the full set of StyleCop rules, there are some where I personally don't see that they help in improving readability or consistency of the code. So questioning the use of a certain rule must be legitimate.

Comment: Appreciate the answer--the questioning of the rules is legitimate, and we are bending over backwards to listen to the concerns of our teammates and make rules that make sense for our team.  We're also looking at every rule before enabling instead of enabling the full suite.  We do code reviews, we are reviewing the standards constantly...it's just so hard to get people to care when they just plain don't, and I'm not sure how to get people to care.  I guess we'll just have to be super thorough looking for those `#pragma disables` if we can't catch that automatically.

Comment: Of course you could write an own tool to check for that (or write an extension for StyleCop - it has an extension API). But then you would again need a way of disabling that when the #pragma is legitimate.